# Larger font in a pdf file when create it from Lyx

Tags: fonts, lyx, pdf, fontsize

I'm using Lyx on Mac and try to get a pdf-file by `cmd + R` combination. However, the font that I get in the pdf file is too small for me. I tried to set the base font as 12pt, but still it's small. I want to have it 16pt or 22pt, for example.

Is there any way? I know nothing about TeX, sorry, please be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Document --> Settings --> Document class. Assuming  you're currently using the default document class, which is called *Article (Standard class)*, change to *Article (Standard class with Extra Font Sizes)*. Now the available base font sizes are 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, and 20pt.

Then you can set for example 17pt as the base size like this:

[image: lyx document settings with extarticle and 17pt set]

Comment: Thanks a million! I did that and succeeded, but there's a new thing now: some lines are not reformatted and go outside the page. Is there any chance to fix that as well? My docs are big, I don't want to rearrange text manually.

Comment: @alekscooper There are several reasons why that would happen I think, so I can't really give a one size fits all answer that fits in a comment. I suggest posting a new question where you show some examples of what happens.